# Module#Refine and Module#used - couldn't understand their use in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can anyone help me here to understand how the below two methods works with some examples ?

> - *Module#Refine*
> - *Module#used*

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "refine", it is a part of an "experimental" feature named [Refinements](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/RefinementsSpec). Refinements are not part of the Ruby 2.0 core spec, as their value and consequences where still discussed between the various Ruby implementors (remember there is more to Ruby than its core implementation, "MRI" - JRuby, Rubinius and others).

Refinements (should they arrive one day in the spec), would allow some kind of "local monkey patching", allowing to patch an existing class only in the scope of a given module. Should you be interested in some parts of the discussions around them, you should take a look at Charles Olivier Nutter [article](http://blog.headius.com/2012/11/refining-ruby.html) on it (he is the main implementor of JRuby) or [this one](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/) from Yehuda Katz.

Regarding "used", as per the source, it does not do much :

```
static VALUE
rb_obj_dummy(void)
{
    return Qnil;
}
```

After some research and a "[call to help](https://twitter.com/headius/status/311887701005701120)", here is Charles Olivier Nutter (JRuby lead implementor) answer :

> #used is called when a module appears in a refinement's "using" call

So your two questions are actually linked.

Comment: Still couldn't understand the `#used` method. :(

Comment: What exactly do you want to "understand" ? What is the problem behind your question ?

Comment: Okay! why or when should we use `Module#used` method? What's the purpose of this method?

Comment: Apparently there is no purpose.

Comment: I *think* it is also related in some ways with Refinements (as it exists in Ruby 2.0 but not in 1.9), but could not find any reliable source about this - and the method is not documented nor implemented (except for a "dummy" implementation returning nil). It does look like JRuby does not implement it either : http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/RubyModule.html

Comment: Got some answer from Charles Olivier Nutter, included in the answer.